Universal cover of a Riemannian surface
Consider an open surface $\Sigma$, we embed it in $R^3$ and assume this embedding is proper so its image is an embedded Riemannian surface (the metric is induced from $R^3$).
Now we look the universal cover of $(\Sigma,g)$. My understanding is that we first look at the universal cover of $\Sigma$ topologically, and assign every fundamental domain a metric $g$. Basically the projection map from the universal cover to the base lifts the metric to $g$ on $\Sigma$ to a metric $\tilde{g}$ on $\tilde{\Sigma}$.
What I don't understand is how we think the image of the universal cover in $R^3$? Is it just the infinite cover of $\Sigma$ itself? So it induces a new map that is an immersion. Does that mean the universal cover of a proper map can be nonproper?
In geometry of submanifolds, people like to look at the universal of the submanifold so it becomes homotopically trivial. But they never describe what the universal cover is, so I am confused.

Your writing is unclear and I could not understand what are you asking. Do you know the definition of a proper map? Can you figure out if, say, the universal covering $\mathbb R\to S^1$ is a proper map or not?

@MoisheKohan Proper map simply means that the preimage of  the intersection of the compact subset of the ambient space with the immersion is compact. So $R\rightarrow S^1$ is not proper.

"Lifts" is the wrong word. You pull back the metric $2$-tensor by the projection map. But why do you think the universal cover of $\Sigma$ naturally embeds in $\Bbb R^3$?

@TedShifrin I am not sure if it naturally embeds. If we only care about the intrinsic geometry of the universal cover, we do not need to care its immersion or embedding. But if I want to know how ambient ball intesect the universal cover, I need to know what the immersion is.
